# Doctrine Entities Relations confusing

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

After some hours trying to understand I can't get the concept clear. I have three entities defined as shown:

```
class Countries
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="flag", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $flag;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Regions", mappedBy="country_id")
     */
    private $regions_in_country;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cities", mappedBy="country_id")
     */
    private $cities_in_country;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->regions_in_country= new ArrayCollection();
        $this->cities_in_country= new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

---

```
class Regions
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="country_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Countries", inversedBy="regions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $countryId;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cities", mappedBy="region_id")
     */
    private $cities_in_region;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->cities_in_region= new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

---

```
class Cities
{
    /**
    * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="country_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Countries", inversedBy="cities_in_country")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $countryId;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="region_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Regions", inversedBy="cities_in_region")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $regionId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;
}
```

The problem is that the Profiler says:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Regions    

The association AppBundle\Entity\Regions#cities_in_region refers to
the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\Cities#region_id which does not exist.
```

But the field region_id in AppBundle\Entity\Cities exists!!

Any suggestion?

**EDITED:**
Thanks Rafix and Alvin for the concepts. I'm a new to Doctrine/Symfony and some times...

In fact what I want to do is to use in a form a select with a CountryType field, the thing is that it uses code_2a as values.

In my entities, like user_profile, I will have a field country with the'code_2a', OneToOne to the entity Country and then use this field in the Region entity. That means that the Country entity will have a field 'code_2a' OneToMany pointing to the Region Entity, which will have a 'code_2a' ManyToOne reversing to Country. Because they are not 'id' I wonder how to do it. there are no examples to figure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes can be created like my example below.
I based this on @rafix 's answer, but there were some problems.

Also, you don't **have** to name your classes in the singular like @rafix indicated, you can name them however you want. But, it's much better practive to do it that way and make your code much easier to read and support.

For example: If you have a class called "Country", then you know a country has "cities", and each one of those "cities" is a "City". So the class refers to the individual object.

Here is the changes I suggest:

```
class Country
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="country_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
   private $country_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="flag", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $flag;

   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Region", mappedBy="country")
    */
   private $regions = null;

   public function __construct() {
       $this->regions = new ArrayCollection();

   }
}
```

---

```
class Region
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="region_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $region_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="regions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region_country_id", referencedColumnName="country_id")
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="City", mappedBy="region")
     */
    private $cities = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->cities = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

---

```
class City
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="city_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $city_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Region", inversedBy="cities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region_id", referencedColumnName="region_id")
     */
    private $region;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;
}
```

Notice, I renamed each of the "id" s in each of the classes so you would know that it is the ID for that particular Entity. For example: The Country class has a "country_id".

Also, since for example, the Country class has "regions", you need to declare the array as "null". Make sure you have the proper `addRegion` to add regions to the array when you finish your code.

Answer (score 1):

you can avoid the Id suffix in the entity fields and you must name the entity classes in singular.

```
class Country
{
    /**
    * @var int
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="flag", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $flag;

   /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Region", mappedBy="country")
   */
   private $regions;

   public function __construct() {
       $this->regions = new ArrayCollection();

   }
}
class Region
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="regions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     private $country;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="City", mappedBy="region")
     */
    private $cities;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->cities = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
class City
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Region", inversedBy="cities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $region;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that in your code the attribute $region in the City entity doesn't has column definition?. The same with $country in Region. Is it a typo?. With the definitions of column I get: 
    The association AppBundle\Entity\Region#cities refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\City#region which is not defined as association, but as field.
    The association AppBundle\Entity\Region#cities refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\City#region which does not exist.

Comment: Now I see my error, Thanks rafix. No you haven't commit a typo. The  M-t-O columns has to be JoinColumn, that's the key. Hope this helps.