# Create a bidirectional many-to-many association with an extra field on doctrine

Tags: database, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, symfony

I work with symfony 3 and doctrine and this is my problem:
I want to create dishes composed of ingredients of different quantity.

The database will look like this:

```
[ Dish ] <===> [ IngredientDish ] <===> [ Ingredient ]
[------]       [----------------]       [------------]
[- name]       [- Dish          ]       [-name       ]
[      ]       [- Ingredient    ]       [            ]
[      ]       [- quantity      ]       [            ]
[------]       [----------------]       [------------]
```

This is my code :

Dish.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="dish")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\DishRepository")
 */
class Dish
{

     /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\IngredientDish",
      *         mappedBy="dish")
      */
     private $ingredientsDish;

     [...]

     public function addIngredientDish(IngredientDish $ingredient)
     {
         $this->ingredientsDish[] = $ingredient;

         return $this;
     }

     public function getIngredientsDish()
     {
         return $this->ingredientsDish;
     }

 }
```

Ingredient.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="ingredient")
 *    @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\IngredientRepository")
 */
 class Ingredient
 {

     /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\IngredientDish",
      *     mappedBy="ingredient")
      * @Assert\Type(type="AppBundle\Entity\IngredientDish")
      */
     private $ingredientsDish;

     [...]

     public function addIngredientDish(IngredientDish $ingredientDish)
     {
         $this->ingredientDish[] = $ingredientDish;

         return $this;
      }

     public function getingredientsDish()
     {
         return $this->ingredients;
     }

 }
```

IngredientDish.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="ingredient_dish")
 *    @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\IngredientDishRepository")
 */
class IngredientDish
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="smallint")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min=1)
     */
    private $quantity = 1;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Ingredient",
     *      inversedBy="ingredientsDish")
     * @Assert\Type(type="AppBundle\Entity\Ingredient")
     */
    private $ingredient;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Dish",
     *      inversedBy="ingredientsDish")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn()
     * @Assert\Type(type="AppBundle\Entity\Dish")
     */
    private $dish;

    public function __construct(Ingredient $ingredient, Dish $dish, $quantity = 1)
    {
        $this->setIngredient($ingredient);
        $this->setDish($dish);
        $this->setQuantity($quantity);
    }

    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    public function setIngredient(Ingredient $ingredient)
    {
        $this->ingredient = $ingredient;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getIngredient()
    {  
        return $this->ingredient;
    }

    public function setDish(Dish $dish)
    {
        $this->dish = $dish;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDish()
    {
        return $this->dish;
    }

}
```

My test code

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

//Get an apple pie
$dish = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Dish')->find(6);

//Get an apple
$ingredient = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Ingredient')->find(11);

$quantityApple = 5;

$ingredientDish = new IngredientDish($ingredient, $dish, $quantityApple);

$ingredient->addIngredientDish($ingredientDish);

$dish->addIngredientDish($ingredientDish);

$em->persist($ingredientDish);
$em->persist($dish);
$em->flush();
```

After execution, i have an interesting entry:

```
mysql> select * from ingredient_dish;
+----+---------------+----------+---------+
| id | ingredient_id | quantity | dish_id |
+----+---------------+----------+---------+
| 1  |            11 |        5 |       6 |
+----+---------------+----------+---------+
```

But after, if I try to get my dish:

```
$dish = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Dish')->find(6);
dump($dish->getIngredientsDish());
```

It has no ingredients :

```
PersistentCollection {#1180 ▼
    -snapshot: []
    -owner: Dish {#1146 ▶}
    -association: array:15 [ …15]
    -em: EntityManager {#1075 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "dish"
    -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#1157 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: ArrayCollection {#1181 ▼
        -elements: [] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< EMPTY
    }
    #initialized: false
}
```

The database is not empty after the execution of my test code, so I think there is an error of getter.
Can you help me, do you see something false ?

Thanks you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that everything is fine, but you got mislead by lazy loading which is apparently smarter than you think it is. ;-)

When you do

```
$dish->getIngredientsDish();
```

you receive `PersistentCollection` which extends `AbstractLazyCollection`.

**But the collection is still not fetched from DB(!)**

Take a look closer into your `var_dump` result

```
PersistentCollection {#1180 ▼
    -snapshot: []
    -owner: Dish {#1146 ▶}
    -association: array:15 [ …15]
    -em: EntityManager {#1075 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "dish"
    -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#1157 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: ArrayCollection {#1181 ▼
        -elements: [] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< EMPTY //<= yeah empty, but...
    }
    #initialized: false // <= it's still not initialized!
}
```

As you can see there's `initialized`  property which says that the collection is still not initialized (not fetched form DB).

Just try to use it. It will fetch the collection on first usage.

Comment: I don't understand really well, when I it : `$dish = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Dish')->find(6); $dish->getIngredientsDish(); dump($dish);` the result of the dump still uninitialized.

Comment: Yes, relations are lazy loaded by default therefore the collection's still uninitialized. Simply use it at was already initialized and it should be fine. E.g. do `foreach` on `$dish->getIngredientsDish();`.

Comment: Ho thanks you ! Doctrine is lazy lazy, I have to do this `foreach ($test as $key => $value) { dump($value->getIngredient()->getName()); }`. And if I want to get all ingredients in juste one query, I have to write it in a repository with the QueryBuilder ? Thanks again !

Comment: No, the whole collection is fetched from DB when you access even one of its elements. If you would do `foreach ($test as $value) { dump($value->getIngredient()->getName()); break;}` which is just a first iteration of the loop. and then dump the whole object, you will see there's whole collection initialized. Also you can see in Symfony's profiler that there was only one query to DB regarding this collection. That's by default. There's also `EXTRA_LAZY` mode, which works a bit different. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First, there are some problems with you annotations mappings.
Make the follow changes:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="dish")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\DishRepository")
 */
class Dish
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="dish_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $dish_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\IngredientDish",
     *         mappedBy="dish")
     */
    private $ingredientsDish = null;

    public function __construct() {
         $this->ingredientsDish = new ArrayCollection();

    }
    ...
}
```

---

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="ingredient_dish")
 *    @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\IngredientDishRepository")
 */
class IngredientDish
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Dish",
     *      inversedBy="ingredientsDish")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dish_id", referencedColumnName="country_id")
     * @Assert\Type(type="AppBundle\Entity\Dish")
     */
    private $dish;
    ...
}
```

In the Dish entity you need to have a constructor for the ArrayCollection, and set it to null.

You can also take a look at this other post of mine (on stackoverflow for a reference:

[Doctrine Entities Relations confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144745/doctrine-entities-relations-confusing/39150593#39150593)

Comment: I don't think constructor is the issue here since it's not called by Doctrine while hydrating data from DB. Also setting `$ingredientsDish = null;` doesn't make sense since it's the default value if other is not specified.

Comment: Thanks @dragoste ! I did not know that about the default value being null. My main concern was seeing that he had a `@ORM\JoinColumn()` that is to say, with no parameters. That just didn't seem right to me.